# Two case when hive conditionals

Tags: sql, hive, conditional-statements, case, hiveql

How can I perform two conditionals on the same CASE WHEN, for example:

```
CASE
    WHEN (column) LIKE '%IPHONE%' AND '%MOBILE%' THEN 'IOS'
    WHEN (column) LIKE '%ANDROID%' AND '%LINUX%' THEN 'ANDROID'
    WHEN (column) LIKE '%LINUX%' THEN 'DESKTOP'
    ELSE 'NA'
END
```

My record shows: Iphone; Mobile; Mac OS X; How can I give a LIKE query with two conditions (Iphone and Mobile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CASE
    WHEN (column LIKE '%IPHONE%') AND (column LIKE '%MOBILE%') THEN 'IOS'
    WHEN (column LIKE '%ANDROID%') AND (column LIKE '%LINUX%') THEN 'ANDROID'
    WHEN column LIKE '%LINUX%' THEN 'DESKTOP'
    ELSE 'NA'
END
```